# How to achieve this layout on buttons and text fields in XCode using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I want to know how can I display the buttons and the text field in exactly this layout on swift.

[image]

Comment: I want to get the exact design as this. I am not able to get the symbols used in the buttons and the text fields, also, I am not able to figure out how to get the (semi-complete) line drawn between the 2 buttons and the 2 text fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Main.storyboard` select a tableview and in the attributes inspector put the style from Plain to `Grouped`.

[image]

You can select a number of prototype cells, and adjust them. The little arrow on the right can be done by selecting a cell, and on the attributes inspector you put the Accessory to `Discloser Indicator`

Comment: Also, can you tell me how can i get the symbols/icons used on the left hand side in the buttons and the text fields?

Comment: Those are just images put in a `UIImageView`. You can download sets of icons for free online. Not sure about the text fields though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to understand the concept of Constraint first. Follow [raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Once you understand this. you can do it in either way using UITableView or separately using UIView containing controls UILabel,UIImage and UITextField

Comment: Please don't post just a link but explain *here, in the answer* what your solution is about. Thank you.

Comment: I already suggested the solution brother,  Keshav can do this by using the UIView containing which controls. Now he has to understand how to apply constraint on them. thats why I have posted the link

Comment: Also, can you tell me how can i get the symbols/icons used on the left hand side in the buttons and the text fields?

Comment: for icons you can use UIImageView and for textfield use UITextfield. for separator you can use UIView or UILabel with height 1px and set background color to grey.  Align your all controls and set constraints for them, thats it.